# Executing the tests from NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

What is the difference between `NUnit GUI`, `NUnit Test Adapter` and `Nunit Command Line` for executing the tests.
1. Pros and Cons of each?
2. When to use Nunit GUI/Test adapter/Command line?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty open ended question, but here is a short overview. All of them run your tests, so the choice is really down to your development process and tastes.

**NUnit GUI**

This program is good for beginners and people who do not like the command line. The usual workflow with the GUI is to work on code in Visual Studio, but leave the GUI running with your tests loaded. Every time you make changes to your code, you compile, then switch to the GUI and run your tests.

The GUI was especially useful before free editions of Visual Studio allowed extensions, but IMHO, now the VS Test Adapter is the better choice, although the GUI does give you a nicer interface.

**Visual Studio Adapter**

This is good because it is integrated with Visual Studio. You can run individual test methods and debug your tests very easily.

The biggest limitation is that it uses the Visual Studio test UI, so is limited by that UI which isn't very good in my opinion.

**Command Line**

The advantage of the command line is flexibility and the fact that it is lightweight. You can filter and debug your tests using it, but it takes a bit of setup. It is also the best way to run your tests on your Continuous Integration server.

The biggest advantage of the command line runner is that it is considered the core runner by the NUnit team and therefore has the most features and testing. Plus, every dev looks cooler on the command line than clicking buttons in a GUI :)